# NSTableCellView Drag Handle

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I've created an NSTableView that uses custom views for each row.  In our design the user single clicks on a row in order to perform an action, which causes the table to be hidden (think a browser bookmarks menu implemented using a table view).  I want the user to be able to enable an editing mode, which causes cells to display a drag handle (iOS style) that they can then use to reorder the rows.  I've got the edit mode working and have implemented the necessary data source methods to enable drag and drop.  The issue I'm struggling with is to only allow the user to drag using the drag handles, instead of being able drag the entire row.  Is there a way to customize the hit testing so I can only have a drag session start when the mouse is over my drag handles?

Here's is an example of the interface in editing mode:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I found the following function that I can override in the NSTableView in order to determine if a drag session should begin:

`- (BOOL)canDragRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes atPoint:(NSPoint)mouseDownPoint;`

This allows me to check if the mouse down point is over the drag handle.